# Changing Colors Individually Instead of Together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn JS/JQuery and am currently working on a little project that is 4 bubbles. When clicked they are supposed to change color individually. I have done this successfully with several switch statements, but I want to optimize my code.

I am able to go through the array colors and get the bubbles to change, but they are sharing an index. I can't figure out the more optimal way to write them with their own indexes without doing several switch statements again. Am I missing something obvious?

Note: To be 100% clear, I **do not** want an answer, I just want guidance. I don't learn from the answer being handed to me. Examples are fine.

```js
/*My JS/JQuery Script*/

let bubbles = document.getElementsByClassName("bubbles");
let colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"];

$(document).ready(function(){
     $(bubbles).click(function(){
        for(colorIndex = 0; colorIndex < colors.length; colorIndex++){
            $(this).css("background-color") = colors[i];
        }
        switch(colors){
            case "red": 
                $(this).css("background-color", "red");
                break;
            case "yellow": 
                $(this).css("background-color", "orange");
                break;
            case "orange":
                $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
                break;
            case "green":
                $(this).css("background-color", "green");
                break;
            case "blue":
                $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
                break;
            case "violet":
                $(this).css("background-color", "violet");
                break;
            default:
                $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
                colorIndex = 0;
                break;
          }
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- My HTML -->
  <body>
    <div id="column">
      <div id="bubble1" class="bubbles"></div>
      <div id="bubble2" class="bubbles"></div>
      <div id="bubble3" class="bubbles"></div>
      <div id="bubble4" class="bubbles"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: One issue that you are going to have is there isn't one way of doing things. Some ways are different but equally useful while others aren't. But I do have a question as I'm not sure what you are trying to do. When you click on a bubble, what color is supposed to be used? I see you have 4 bubbles but more colors so the numbers don't correspond

Comment: @imvain2 I'm sorry I wasn't clear. When you click the bubble it is supposed to move through the array and the bubble is supposed to change color depending on the index. So if you click bubble1 it will start red, then orange, then yellow, etc. They don't do this individually, instead if I click bubble1 it'll turn red and then if I click bubble2 it will be orange and not red.

Comment: So each button will transition through ALL of the colors? So each button will kind of slowly strobe through the colors?

Answer (score 0):

The better way as setting the color via inline-CSS is to add a class to the field and writing in CSS the styling.

Here an example.

```
$(this).classList.add('green');
$(this).classList.remove('red');
```

and in your styling

```
.green { background-color: green; }
.red   { background-color: red; }
```